# Editing fetch xml in chart

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

```xml
  <fetchcollection>
    <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
      <entity name="contact">
        <attribute groupby="true" alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0" name="hpcrm_currentsegmentid" />
        <order alias ="new_rank" descending="false"/>
        <attribute alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" name="hpcrm_revenue" aggregate="sum" />
        <attribute alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_13" name="hpcrm_aum" aggregate="sum" />
        <attribute alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_14" name="hpcrm_revenuelastyear" aggregate="sum" />
        <link-entity name="hpcrm_businesstier" from="hpcrm_businesstierid" to="hpcrm_currentsegmentid" alias="aa" > 
        </link-entity>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
  </fetchcollection>
  <categorycollection>
    <category alias="_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0">
      <measurecollection>
        <measure alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0" />
      </measurecollection>
      <measurecollection>
        <measure alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_13" />
      </measurecollection>
      <measurecollection>
        <measure alias="_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_14" />
      </measurecollection>
      <measurecollection>
        <measure alias="new_rank" />
      </measurecollection>
    </category>
  </categorycollection>
```

I am  generating chart, but want to  apply order by attribute which is present in another entity to which this entity has an `n:1` relationship. Here the `new_rank` attribute is present in the `businesstier` Entity.

```xml
<link-entity name="hpcrm_businesstier" from="hpcrm_businesstierid" 
  to="hpcrm_currentsegmentid" alias="aa" >
```

Here I am joining the business tier to the contact entity.

But I'm getting an invalid XML error when I try to import the XML.

> The specified XML file "Revenue_AUM by Current Segment.xml" is either
>   not valid XML or does not conform to the chart schema

Answer (score 0):

Move your order statement inside of the linked entity.  Granted not your query, but something like:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" count="50" version="1.0">
    <entity name="account">
        <attribute name="accountnumber" />
        <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentaccountid">
            <attribute name="accountnumber" />
            <order attribute="accountnumber" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```